# Meeting Invite on Lotus notes using Java API

Tags: java, email, outlook, jakarta-mail, lotus-notes

I am getting some problem while sending meeting invite in lotus notes.i am trying to see in the accept/decline feature format but instead it is just coming up as add to Calendar Feature only.So if anyone can help me with this would be great.here is my code

```
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", SMTP_HOST_NAME);

        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "false");

        Authenticator auth = new SMTPAuthenticator();
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, auth);

        session.setDebug(debug);

        MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
        msg.addHeaderLine("method=REQUEST");
        msg.addHeaderLine("charset=UTF-8");
        msg.addHeaderLine("component=VEVENT");

        InternetAddress addressFrom = new InternetAddress(from);
        msg.setFrom(addressFrom);

        if (!(recipients == null)) {

            InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[recipients.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < recipients.length; i++) {
                addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(recipients[i]);

            }

            log.debug("setting to recipients");
            msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, addressTo);

        }
        if (!(recipientCC == null)) {

            InternetAddress[] addressCC = new InternetAddress[recipientCC.length];
            for (int j = 0; j < recipientCC.length; j++) {
                addressCC[j] = new InternetAddress(recipientCC[j]);

            }
            log.debug("setting cc recipients");
            msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC, addressCC);

        }

        msg.setSubject(subject);

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        StringBuffer buffer = sb
                .append("BEGIN:VCALENDAR\n"
                        + "X-LOTUS-CHARSET:UTF-8\n"
                        + "PRODID:-//Lotus Development Corporation//NONSGML Notes 8.5//EN_C\n"
                        + "VERSION:2.0\n"
                        + "BEGIN:VEVENT\n"
                        + "CATEGORIES:Meeting\n"
                        + "STATUS:NEEDS ACTION\n"
                        + "DTSTART:20130727T184555\n"
                        + "DTEND:20130727T194555\n"
                        + "DTSTAMP:20130727T184555\n"
                        + "SEQUENCE:0\n"
                        + "EXPECT:IMMEDIATE\n"
                        + "DESCRIPTION:Steve and John to review newest proposal material\n"
                        + "SUMMARY:"
                        + subject
                        + "\n"
                        + "CLASS:PUBLIC\n"
                        + "UID:86DC83601F9625C465257BB40047FE17-Lotus_Notes_Generated\n"
                        + "X-LOTUS-UPDATE-SEQ:1\n"
                        + "X-LOTUS-UPDATE-WISL:$S:1;$L:1;$B:1;$R:1;$E:1;$W:1;$O:1;$M:1\n"
                        + "X-LOTUS-NOTESVERSION:2\n"
                        + "X-LOTUS-NOTICETYPE:I\n"
                        + "X-LOTUS-APPTTYPE:3\n"
                        + "X-LOTUS-CHILD-UID:86DC83601F9625C465257BB40047FE17\n"
                        + "END:VEVENT\n" + "END:VCALENDAR\n");

        // Create the message part
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

        // Fill the message
        messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-Class",
                "urn:content-classes:calendarmessage");
        messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID", "calendar_message");
        messageBodyPart
                .setDataHandler(new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(
                        buffer.toString(), "text/calendar")));// very
                                                                // important
        // Create a Multipart
        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

        // Add part one
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

        // Put parts in message

        msg.setContent(multipart);
        log.debug("Sending mail");
        Transport.send(msg);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a group event instead of a public event, if you want to be able to respond. You can read everything about this [in the RFC 2446](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2446#section-4.2.1).

It is mandatory to define attendees for a group event to work (see Chapter 4.2 in above documentation). This might look like this:

```
ATTENDEE;ROLE=CHAIR;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED;CN=BIG A:Mailto:A@example.com
ATTENDEE;RSVP=TRUE;TYPE=INDIVIDUAL;CN=B:Mailto:B@example.com
```

RSVP=TRUE lets B respond.

If you need to make sure, that appointments do not get mixed up, generate a unique uid for every event and reuse it if something changes. Otherwise you will not be able to send updates.

Comment: Torsten,As you have said to create a group even instead of a public event,I have done that way but it's still giving the same output as before.Maybe it's because i am using msg.setRecipients to send mails to respective persons.Should i remove that too.If yes,then how would i'll be able to send mails to persons.

Comment: Why don't you send a native (Lotus Notes or any other mail client) invitation to a web-client (gmail, gmx, soemthing else) and just check the difference in the files... How you send the mail should not be of any relevance for the invitation, except that e.g. Gmail does not let you accept or decline if the invitiation comes from your own address...

Comment: Thanks torsten but i have find the answer for this query.Actually Lotus notes ask for a property named "X-LOTUS-BROADCAST" which is by default true so if we make it false the invite goes as a accept/reject meeting invite.